# Mock External API - Interaction not exercised

Tags: api, mocking, web-api-testing

I have just started to use Pactum to unit test my API endpoints.

In one of my API endpoints, I am calling an external API and I have tried to mock this external API. My code clearly calls the external API.

However, my test fails and I get an error (the actual endpoint `32` is just a sample, it is not hardcoded in the actual codes):
`Interaction not exercised: GET - https://62b32eab4f851f87f4563d9b.mockapi.io/user/32`

Here is a sample of my test:

```
it('should update record', async () => {
  await spec()
  .post('http://localhost:3000/user')
  .withJson({
    "name": "helen",
    "city": "London"
  })
  .useInteraction({
    request: {
      method: 'GET',
      path: 'https://62b32eab4f851f87f4563d9b.mockapi.io/user/32'
  },
  response: {
    status: 200,
    body: [
        {"name":"Jerald Labadie","country":"Buckinghamshire","city":"Lake Junebury","email":"Alf_Schneider81@gmail.com","id":"32"}
      ]
  }
  })
  .expectStatus(200)
  .wait(3000)
})
```

I know I can just connect to mockapi for the mock, but is there any way to resolve this and do this locally?

Answer (score 0):

While using mocks, we need to divert the traffic from your service to the local mock server. Can be achieved simply by using environment variables.

```js
const mock_url = process.env.MOCK_URL || 'https://<key>.mockapi.io';
```

Now, start the sever by initiating the `MOCK_URL` environment variable to the pactum's mock server url. Assuming pactum mock server is running on localhost `9393`.

```bash
export MOCK_URL=http://localhost:9393 && node server.js
```

Now update your interaction to handle the traffic.

```js
it('should update record', async () => {
  await spec()
  .useInteraction({
    request: {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/user/32'
    },
    response: {
      status: 200,
      body: [ {"name":"Jerald Labadie","country":"Buckinghamshire","city":"Lake Junebury","email":"Alf_Schneider81@gmail.com","id":"32"} ]
    }
  })
  .post('http://localhost:3000/user')
  .withJson({
    "name": "helen",
    "city": "London"
  })
  .expectStatus(200)
})
```